# redirect nmap to stdout instead of writing it into file

Tags: nmap, stdout

I'm creating python program running `nmap -sn` on a remote server.

Is there a way to redirect `nmap -oX` directly into stdout or a different channel instead of writing it into a file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by passing a hyphen character as the argument to `-oX`, like this:

```
nmap -oX - <other args> <target>
```

From the manpage:

> This causes Nmap to deactivate interactive output, and instead print results in the format you specified to the standard output stream. So the command nmap -oX - target will send only XML output to stdout. Serious errors may still be printed to the normal error stream, stderr.

To avoid errors polluting your XML output, you may want to redirect the `stderr` stream to the null device with `2> /dev/null` or to a file if you wish to capture it.

*General note:* use of the hyphen like this is actually a [POSIX](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html) guideline (section 12.2, guideline 13) and is widely used across the spectrum of *nix commands, so it's a good thing to keep in mind when faced with the same problem in a different context:

> For utilities that use operands to represent files to be opened for either reading or writing, the '-' operand should be used only to mean standard input (or standard output when it is clear from context that an output file is being specified).